# How to prevent form double submit in form that have Validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, validation

I have web form that have `TextBox` with `Validator` :

```
<script src="../script/jquery-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="v" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Go" CausesValidation="true" />
</form>
```

I want to disable submit `button` when form submitted but this code also disable submit `button` when `TextBox` is not valid by `Validator`(is empty).

*I want a way for all ASP.NET Validators,not only `RequiredFieldValidator`*.

How can I disable submit `button` only in real submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the global `Page_IsValid` variable is set to `true` before disabling the submit button:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () {
                if (Page_IsValid)
                    $('input[type=submit]', this).prop('disabled', true);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="v" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Go" CausesValidation="true" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MajidR: It works for me in Firefox 22.0. Make sure you're not working with a cached page. Also, does it work for you in IE or Chrome?

Comment: @MajidR: I updated my answer with the entire contents of Default.aspx which I've tested with IE 11, Firefox 22, and Chrome 29. Try creating a new ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms project with this code and see if it works for you. Note: I put `if (!this.IsPostBack) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` inside `Page_Load` to simulate a delay; otherwise, the page posts back too quickly to see the button get disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
         if($.trim($('#<%=name.ClientID%>').val()) !='' ){ //if textbox not empty
            $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         }else{
            e.preventDefault();
         }
        });
    });
```

[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
 $('input[type=submit]', this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I want a way for all `Validator`s not only `RequiredFieldValidator`!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (name.Text != String.Empty) {
        submit.Enabled = false;
    } else {
        submit.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

this Code without java script